# Security Patch SUPEE-10570 — Error "Hunk #4 FAILED at 1973" during installation

Tags: upgrade, patches, enterprise-1.13

I am trying to apply the patch SUPEE-10570 into a Magento Enterprise store (1.13.0.1). However, I am receiving the following error message:

```
Hunk #4 FAILED at 1973.
1 out of 4 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Import/Entity/Product.php.rej
```

At first I thought it could be due to a missing patch, but it looks like I already have all of them.

List of applied patches:

```
 SUPEE-5344 
 SUPEE-1533 
 SUPEE-5994 
 SUPEE-6285 
 SUPEE-6482_EE_1.13.0.2 
 SUPEE-6788 
 SUPEE-7405-EE-1-13-0-2 
 SUPEE-7405 
 SUPEE-1533 
 SUPEE-3941 
 SUPEE-8788 
 PATCH_SUPEE-9767_EE_1.13.0.1_v2 
 SUPEE-10266-1.13.1.0 
 SUPEE-10415-1.13.0.1 
 SUPEE-9652
```

What else should I be looking for?

Thank you.

Comment: compare with latest version Magento any core file changed in app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Import/Entity/Product.php

Comment: @RamaChandranM I would love to do so but I do not have access to download it. I already asked access but it was suggested to me to keep looking for missing patches.